# Objective C code base will work on Swift directly?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have Objective C codebase project. Will this work with Swift codebase directly? Or I must to have to convert to Swift to make it Swift supported? Is there any apple's official links related my question?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/ is a good starting point for Swift related information. It links to "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Apple Documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/Migration.html):-

Before you begin migrating your codebase, make sure that your Objective-C and Swift code will have optimal compatibility. This means tidying up and modernizing your existing Objective-C codebase. Your existing code should follow modern coding practices to make it easier to interact with Swift seamlessly. For a short list of practices to adopt before moving forward, see [Adopting Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150).