# How do you prepare an Objective-C framework for Swift use?

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have an existing framework & bundle written in Objective-C and would like to access it in Swift.

How would I go about doing that?

---

Here's what I got:
1) Attempting to import the ObjC framework.  Notice that I'm not successful.
[image]

Within the Objective-C framework project... attempting to make it usable for Swift.  
I set the 'Defines Module' to YES:

[image]

I setup the bridge header within the ObjC framework app:
[image]

Yet I'm unable to access the framework.  Apparently Xcode 6.1.1 doesn't convert the Objective-C to an importable Swift framework interface.

What am I missing?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287795/objective-c-code-base-will-work-on-swift-directly/27287842#27287842

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, make sure your objective-c code is up to date

Then you add your objective-c code to your project, xcode will automatically ask you if you want to create a bridging header.

In your bridging header file, you just need to include your objective-c header files

example:

```
#import MyClass.h
```

save your header, and after that, you can test by trying to use your objective-c classes inside your swift code base

Comment: Will this work for a framework which will be shared by various ObjC and Swift clients?

Comment: can you elaborate a little?

Comment: import objective-c to swift project should work: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: @tyt_g207 yeah, this article details creating a bridging header

Comment: I describe a little bit about importing framework & library. Pay attention with 'Defines Module' = YES : "When you import an external framework, make sure the Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set to Yes."

Comment: I have an existing ObjC project that's using a custom framework;
accessed by the classic #import <MyMobile/MyMobile.h>.   I want
to do an import myMobile in Swift.

Comment: didnt I just explain how to do that?  create a bridging header.  follow the guide linked above in the comments

Comment: But how would you IMPORT the framework?  Rather than using the ObjC syntax: <MyMobile/MyMobile.h>, I should use the Swift syntax: "import MyMobile".  I'm assuming the solution consists of a) 'Defines Module' and b) the bridging header.